# AssertionError in WebGL build on Unity 2021.2.8

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, webgl

After I tried to upgrade the project from Unity 2019.4.31 to 2021.2.8, WebGL fails on build.

At first I used the old WebGL template i had, then i tested with the default Unity template but the errors stay the same.I tried normal & clean build.Restarted Unity and search about it for a while but I didn't come up with any results. The error is the following and occurs with 4-5 files.

Building C:...\webgl-test\TemplateData\style.css failed with output: assert.js:385 throw err; ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid preprocessor argument: TOTAL_MEMORY=-2147483648 at Object. (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.8f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Preprocess.js:18:12) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 { generatedMessage: false, code: 'ERR_ASSERTION', actual: false, expected: true, operator: '==' }

Answer (score 0):

I know its been already 2 months but I found a workaround. No idea why it does that though but here it is. Go into the ProjectSettings folder, and open the *ProjectSettings.asset* file. Changing the *webGLMemorySize* from 2048 to 2032 made it work for me. No idea why it does this, but i hope it helps!